# How to write to and read from a file in my assets folder in a flutter app?

Tags: file, flutter, dart, readfile, writefile

I am trying to write to and read from a file that is in the assets folder in a flutter app. Generally, how should it be done? I tried the following approach:-

```
void writeToFile(String data) async {
  final String filename = 'colors.json';
  await rootBundle.load('assets/docs/colors.json').then((f){
    print("file loaded successfully.");
    File file = File(filename);
    file.writeAsString(data);
  });
}
```

However, this results in the following error: `E/flutter ( 4944): FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'colors.json' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)`

OS: Mac Catalina

pubspec entry:

```
assets:
- assets/docs/colors.json
```

Comment: Did you add the write permission ?

Comment: write permission to what? I do not intend to write to the android or ios device. I would like to write something to the file that's in the assets folder of my app, that too in the background. User may not have access to writing as well...

Comment: though tried that, still it didn't work. Still the same error message.

Comment: Let me check bro. Give me a minute, I'm working on it.

Comment: You can't write to, or update assets. They are read only.

Comment: What if i would like to record logs of my app in one of my source files, only for testing purposes?

Comment: @iMutjtaba8488 Did you manage to write to the file on assets folder after all?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write the files in the assets. But you can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to save the modified file in app directory.

Per documentation "[Adding assets and images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)"

> An asset is a file that is bundled and deployed with your app, and is
> accessible at runtime.
>
> ...
>
> During a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called
> the asset bundle that apps read from at runtime.